# Access sqlite file from package

Tags: android, sqlite

Its all about security. My purpose is to get sqlite file from assets folder & copy it to sd card. It's fine. But now i want to put that sqlite file in one of my package & copy it to sd card.Is it possible?

To copy sqlite file From Assets:

```
private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_ASSETNAME);

    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
        myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();

}
```

So how can i copy my sqlite file from package to sdcard?

Structure::

```
  - com.package.packagename
       -sqlitefilename.sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

> So how can i copy my sqlite file from package to sdcard?

Replace `new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+DB_NAME)` with something that points to external storage (e.g., `new FileOutputStream(new File(getExternalFilesDir(), DB_NAME))`). Make sure that you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, if your `minSdkVersion` is set to 18 or lower.

Comment: I have my sqlite file in my package, how can i give path for it?

Comment: @geet: The same way you are right now: you copy the file from assets to a file on external storage.

Comment: @geet: Oh, if by "from package" you mean "from internal storage", then your `FileInputStream` would presumably be from `DB_PATH+DB_NAME`, where you copied the file from your assets earlier.